# Is there any way to apply theme changes immediately?

Tags: windows-phone-7

**Is there any way to apply theme changes immediately when the application is re-activated?
The dark/light seems to be the same as it started up.**

```
   // Determine the visibility of the dark background.
    Visibility darkBackgroundVisibility =
        (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];

    // Write the theme background value.
    if (darkBackgroundVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("background = dark");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("background = light");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [Phoney Tools](http://phoney.codeplex.com/) library and check the [PhoneTheme.IsDarkTheme](http://phoney.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Phone%20Resources%20classes&referringTitle=Home) property. I have used this before and it seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. because this property does the exactly same thing as the code I post. [link](http://phoney.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80d07f6c75c5#PhoneyTools%2fSystemResources%2fPhoneThemes.cs)